# firebase signinwithpopup() give me blank page when use it inside onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

i have problem with react when i try to sign to firebase using google auth

i use this syntax to init firebase

```
const configier = {
apiKey: "xxxxxxxcxxxxxxxxxxxx",
authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxx"


 };


  firebase.initializeApp(configier);
  

  export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
  export const auth = firebase.auth();
  
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
  export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

and then in sign in component when i try to put signInWithGoogle like this

```
<CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle} >sign In With Google</CustomButton>
```

i got blank page

[image: blank page]

i try to use signinwithredirect but it not work also

but when i run signinwithpopup in sign-in component constroctor it's work

also when i added () to signinwithpopup inside onclick to be like this

```
<CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle()} >sign In With Google</CustomButton>
```

it work but it work directly when page is loading and i wan't to work when i press on sign in button

i try to use it inside anonymous function like this

```
onclick{()=> signInWithGoogle()}
```

but it also not work i try all solution but it not work

i hope any one can help me

Comment: Needs more context. Do you have any errors that popup? Have you also tried calling `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` directly in the onClick handler instead of signInWithGoogle? The reason I ask this is because firebase relies heavily on `this`, and it requires making sure `this` is the right context.

Comment: I tried to import auth and provider and do firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider) inside anonymous function inside onclick but it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any obvious problems unfortunately. The only difference I had was that my signInWithGoogle looked like `() => firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())`

Comment: @hrgui i try it but it not work . i make screenshot to provide details
https://ibb.co/Sv3msgs i hop you can help me ,

Comment: Instead of `auth.signInWithPopup`, did you try putting  `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup` directly like my comment?

Comment: @hrgui yes i try it and not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was resolved by using event.preventDefault() inside onSubmit in form

Answer (score 0):

fell down on this. If event.preventDefault() worked, it may be because your button is inside a  and triggers `form.onsubmit`

To prevent that, the button must have `type="button"`

Doing `<button type="button" onClick={signInWithGoogle} >sign In With Google</button>`  should solve the issue more cleanly.

Hope it'll help someone in the future.